# Swift: Can I (run-time-checked) look up a CodingKey's corresponding member value?

Tags: swift, reflection, codable

With a `CaseIterable` `CodingKeys` enum and `Mirror` I can almost implement a runtime-type-checked version of the compiler-magic `Encodable` implementation. Almost, but not quite, because from a `CodingKey` value I can't get back to the enum case name, which I need to look up the matching value via `Mirror(reflecting: myEncodable)`.

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case defaultName // default: .stringValue is also the myEncodable member name
    case nonDefaultName = "some-other-name" // .stringValue is not the myEncodable name, no access to "nonDefaultName"
}
```

I would have expected to be able to find the case name somehow via `Mirror(reflecting: CodingKeys.nonDefaultName)` but that doesn't seem to be the case.

1. Am I missing something? Is this in fact possible using Mirror? (I'm still on Xcode 9, by the way, faking `CaseIterable` until I get the real thing.)
2. Any alternative ways to get to the same goal (guarantee that all members mentioned in `CodingKeys` get looked up on the object and fed to the `Encoder`)?

Comment: You've probably figured this out by now, but `CodingKey` has a `stringValue` property which will give you the key's name (or in this case, the property/member name)

Comment: @mattsven the `stringValue` property here gives `"some-other-name"`, my problem is to find the enum case name as used in Swift code (here `"nonDefaultName"`).

Comment: Ah, I didn't parse that part of your question correctly. Have you looked into other ways of associating the case name with your `some-other-name` without setting its value? One option that comes to mind is a custom Encoder/Decoder that asks your Codable object for use by passing it a CodingKey (or something along those lines, you could even store the mapping inside your `CodingKeys`, just not as a raw value of a case).

Comment: @mattsven I ended up tweaking things so I could use the compiler-provided `Encoder` implementation, so the original goal (ensure that a custom `Encoder` doesn't forget any properties) disappeared. My best solution so far for the original goal is a round-trip encode-then-decode test: because the `Decoder` _is_ checked for coverage, if the test passes you can be fairly confident the `Encoder` is ok. Special care needed for properties with defaults though, especially optionals!